# Shuffling image views positions

Tags: java, android

I am making a pair matching game, where there are 8 image views with 4 different images. I am wondering when the page loads is there anyway to swap the positions of the image views?

So that the order of each image changes each time?

Answer (score 1):

*Try this:*

```
     private final int imageArray[] = {
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6
     };
```

**Shuffle:**

```
static void shuffleArray(int[] arr)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Swap
            int a = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = a;
        }
    }
```

**Call the shuffle method and pass your image array as an argument:**

```
shuffleArray(imageArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the layouts of the image views which would require a lot of re-rendering, it would be more ideal to use an algorithm to randomly select out the images and set the images of the image views in order. This way you will still have a random ordering of pairs without having the shuffle around the layouts themselves. Note, you would also need to reassign any appropriate properties of the imageviews such as tags for a specific image you may be using.

Comment: see currently i am using an array full of images which is randomised and an image is chosen at random to fill each image view using 'i'. The problem i am facing to get the same image after the first is drawn i have to put 'i' again before it is randomised again to choose the next pair of images.

Comment: but because i need two of the same images this is the way i have to do it, do you recommend any other way to go around this?

Comment: What I suggested should still work for you, just double fill the array so each image has one duplicate in the array so the array is size 8 and not 4.

Comment: the array has 26 different images and 4 are chosen, if i duplicate them the chances of getting the same image are very high

Comment: If you must shuffle the layouts that is doable too, just create a new linearlayout and add the imageviews to it, remove the old linearlayout and add the new one to your main layout.